# How can I reach a lore text?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to get the text from the lore of the item in the main hand and store it as a score value:

```
execute as @p store result score @s kC run data get entity @s SelectedItem.tag.display.Lore ...
```

But I have no idea how to continue the path to get the text as an output

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution to the problem by developing more steps:

1. As the text in the lore comes from a scoreboard value, I stored the score as an impossible enchantment for the item (a stick in my case), so that existing ones don't get overwritten, using the item modifier `set_enchantments`.
2. Copy-paste the enchantment level in a custom tag (Durability in my case), using the item modifier:
   `copy_nbt ("source": "SelectedItem.tag.Enchantments.[{id:\"minecraft:Your_enchantment\"}].lvl") ("target":"Your custom Tag")`, using replace as the operation.
3. Remove the enchantment to prevent the unwanted glint on the item by using the item modifier `set_enchantments`, setting the enchantment level to `0`.

And this is all so that you can then access the value stored in the item with the path `SelectedItem.tag.YourCustomTag`.